# R Create a new column that identifies if row is the last entry for a user of the type

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, dplyr

I'm trying to create a new column, presumably using mutate, that will identify if whether the row meets a few criteria.  Basically, for each user, I want to identify the final row (by Time) for a certain DataCode. Only some DataCodes are applicable (1000 and 2000 in the example below), and others should return NA (3000 here).  I've been trying to work this through in my head, and all I can think is a really long mutate item with a number of If statements.  Is there a more elegant way?

The IsFinal column below demonstrates what the product would be.

```
 User Time  DataCode Data     IsFinal
 101  10    1000     50       0
 101  20    2000     300      1
 101  30    3000     150      NA
 101  40    1000     250      1
 101  50    3000     300      NA
 102  10    2000     50       0
 102  20    1000     150      0
 102  30    1000     150      0
 102  40    2000     350      1
 102  50    3000     150      NA
 102  60    1000     50       1
```

Comment: `mutate(IsFinal = case_when(grepl("1000", .$DataCode) ~ 0, grepl("2000", .$DataCode) ~ 1, TRUE ~NA))`. Not sure the `.$` is needed in the latest dplyr.

Comment: @RobertMc does this account for the User or Time? I will try it out

Comment: @RobertMc I'm getting an error when I run this that looks like TestP2 <- mutate(TestP,IsFinal = case_when(grepl("1000", .$DataCode) ~ 0, grepl("2000", .$DataCode) ~ 1, TRUE ~NA))
Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : object '.' not found

Comment: Ah, ok, if you want you can change the logical condition to meet what it is you need. The main point is the use of `case_when()`; that will save you all the ifelses!

Comment: Yeah, dplyr has changed the way `case_when()` works in the latest release (.7). If you include a reproducible dataset, I can try it out here.

Comment: @RobertMc does this work? structure(list(User = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 
102L, 102L, 102L, 102L), Time = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 10L, 
20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L), DataCode = c(1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 1000L, 
3000L, 2000L, 1000L, 1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 4000L), Data = c(50L, 
300L, 150L, 250L, 300L, 50L, 150L, 150L, 350L, 150L, 50L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), .Names = c("User", "Time", "DataCode", "Data"))

Comment: yup, next time you could put it in the question, though :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This desires what you need by using ***`merge` and `dplyr` package***:

```
library(dplyr)
new.tab <- query.tab %>%
            group_by(User, DataCode) %>%
            arrange(Time) %>%
            filter(DataCode != 3000) %>% 
            mutate(IsFinal = ifelse(row_number()==n(),1,0))

fin.tab  <- merge(new.tab, query.tab, all.x = FALSE, all.y = TRUE)
```

---

If you want to do ***everything inside `dplyr`*** then this is your answer:

```
fin.tab <-
 query.tab %>%
  group_by(User, DataCode) %>%
   arrange(User,Time) %>%
    mutate(IsFinal = ifelse(DataCode == 3000 , NA, 
                             ifelse(row_number()==n(),1,0)))
```

*Both of these solutions will give:*

```
> fin.tab

#    User Time DataCode Data IsFinal 
# 1   101   10     1000   50       0 
# 2   101   20     2000  300       1 
# 3   101   30     3000  150      NA 
# 4   101   40     1000  250       1 
# 5   101   50     3000  300      NA 
# 6   102   10     2000   50       0 
# 7   102   20     1000  150       0 
# 8   102   30     1000  150       0 
# 9   102   40     2000  350       1 
# 10  102   50     3000  150      NA 
# 11  102   60     1000   50       1
```

***Data:***

```
query.tab <- structure(list(User = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 
102L, 102L, 102L, 102L), Time = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 10L, 
20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L), DataCode = c(1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 1000L, 
3000L, 2000L, 1000L, 1000L, 2000L, 3000L, 1000L), Data = c(50L, 
300L, 150L, 250L, 300L, 50L, 150L, 150L, 350L, 150L, 50L)), .Names = c("User", 
"Time", "DataCode", "Data"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

***Note:*** Read history of edits. It may give you some insight how to handle similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Is it feasible for you to make an array of the approved codes? That would make the `if` statement much simpler.

```
# Can you obtain list of viable codes?
codes <- c("2000", "1000")
# Can you put them in order?
goodcodes <- codes[order(codes)]
# last item in ordered goodcodes should be the end code
endcode <- goodcodes[length(goodcodes)]

testcodes <- c("0500", "1000", "2000", "3000")
n <- length(testcodes)
IsFinal <- rep(0, n)

for (i in 1:n) {
  if (testcodes[i] %in% goodcodes) {
    if (testcodes[i] == endcode) (IsFinal[i] = 1)
  } else (IsFinal[i] = NA)
}

> IsFinal
[1] NA  0  1 NA
>
```

Comment: that would work for identifying the relevant rows, but it doesn't address the user or the time

Answer (score 2):

In base R, we can use `ave` along with `duplicated` and its `fromLast` argument to get the binary values. Then replace the desired values with NA. Using the data in @masoud's answer.

```
# get binary values for final DataCode by user
query.tab$IsFinal <- with(query.tab,
                         ave(DataCode, User, FUN=function(x) !duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)))
# Fill in NA values
is.na(query.tab$IsFinal)  <- query.tab$DataCode %in% c(3000)
```

This returns

```
query.tab
   User Time DataCode Data IsFinal
1   101   10     1000   50       0
2   101   20     2000  300       1
3   101   30     3000  150      NA
4   101   40     1000  250       1
5   101   50     3000  300      NA
6   102   10     2000   50       0
7   102   20     1000  150       0
8   102   30     1000  150       0
9   102   40     2000  350       1
10  102   50     3000  150      NA
11  102   60     1000   50       1
```

Note that this assumes that the data is ordered by user-time. This can be achieved with a call to `order` prior to using the code above.

```
query.tab <- query.tab[order(query.tab$User, query.tab$Time),]
```

Comment: I always appreciate base R answers. Apart from your awesome answer +1.

Comment: If this would work, it would be more flexible for dealing with large varieties of DataCode. But it doesn't work for me. I don't understand your DataCode$IsFinal, because those are two different columns in the same table.

Comment: Sorry a typo. It's corrected. thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @lmo can you explain to me how this handles the time? I assume it has to do with ave and fromLast, but I don't understand it.

Comment: It assumes that the data is ordered by user-time. I'll add that to the post.